# javascript - select json object item based on array value

Tags: javascript

if i have an array of values:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

and a json object:

```
var tester = {'test1' : 'test 1 value', 'test2' : 'test 2 value' }
```

how can i use the array values as a selector to the json object.

I tried:  `tester.myarray[0]`

but that obviously didnt work.

EDIT:

Additionally, i might need to work with nested values like:

```
 var myArray = ['test1', 'test2']

 var tester = {'test1' : { 'test2' : 'test 1/2 value'}}
```

so in this example i have an array, `myArray` which essentially contains the path of where to find the value in the json object.  i.e `tester.test1.test2`.

I would expect to based on the array be able to find the value in the json object

Importantly, the size of the path is not known up front so i assume i will need to loop over the array values to build the path

Comment: What should happen if some value doesn't exist in the object?

Comment: it should just be ignored

Comment: Nope. That is not clear. Can you please show what exactly is your expected output, in both the cases?

Comment: added an explanation to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the corresponding elements from the object

```
var array1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
    tester = {'test1' : 'test 1 value', 'test2' : 'test 2 value' };

console.log(array1.map(function(currentKey) {
    return tester[currentKey];
}));
# [ 'test 1 value', 'test 2 value', undefined ]
```

Edit: As per your latest edit, if you want to get the data from the nested structure, you can do it with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this

```
console.log(myArray.reduce(function(result, current) {
    return result[current];
}, tester));
# test 1/2 value
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the expression you're looking for.

```
tester[myarray[0]]
```

Comment: thank you this works.  i edited my question slightly just now (sorry).  Just an additional requirement regarding possible nesting

Comment: I recommend going over to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and trying this stuff out.  Constructions such as `a[b[c[d]]]` and `a[b][c][d]` are totally fine.